# setMainPage does not seem to work when i set the Id using angular tags any idea why?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

```
#Menu code#

    <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-repeat="list in pages" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('{{list.PageId}}.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon></ons-icon>
        Home {{ list.PageTitle }}
    </ons-list-item>

#Slider code#

<ons-template ng-repeat="list in pages" id="{{list.PageId}}.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
        <div class="center">SirBaniyas Forum</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <ons-row style="margin-top:0px; background-color:#262217;">
            <div class="page__conbg">
                <div style="position:absolute; top:46px; width:100%; background-image:url(images/strip1.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; text-align:center;">
                    <img src="images/logo_trans.png" alt=""/> 
                </div>
          </div>
        </ons-row>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

FYI: If i dont use the angular tags and put a plain string the slider works just fine 
The reason for putting the angular tag is because i need to generate the menu and the content dynamically

Comment: so you're using angular to generate the onclick base on the listitem but with this code... you always load the page with id = page1.html??? You have to find a way to generate that page ID on the fly (via angular scope as well), you can't just use a static iD in the angular tags.

Comment: Getting the page id's on the fly also does not work. Is it because onsen loads before angular can interpret the code ??

Comment: How about trying to create an angular function and call it instead?
like... `ng-onclick="loadPage()"`

Then in angular controller:
`$scope.loadPage = function () {
    menu.setMainPage($scope.list.pageId);
}`

Also note that your page id is including the ".html" in your case....

Comment: Another thing, I'm not sure if angular could generate **ons-template** as it does on **ons-list-item**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So here could be your answer. Basically, you'd have only one **ons-template** but the content of it will be generated dynamically based on whatever menuitem you clicked. This is just a simple sample... but you'll get the idea.

**index.html**

```
<body>

<ons-navigator  title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" >

    <ons-page>

      <ons-toolbar>

        <div class="center">Basic List</div>

      </ons-toolbar>

      <br>      

      <ons-list>

        <ons-list-header>Numbers</ons-list-header>

        <ons-list-item ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-click="loadPage(page.pageId)">{{page.pageTitle}}</ons-list-item>

      </ons-list>

    </ons-page>

  </ons-navigator>



 <ons-template id="templatePage">

  <ons-page>

      <ons-toolbar>

        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>

        <div class="center">{{pageTitle()}}</div>

      </ons-toolbar>

    <p><h2>{{pageContent()}}</h2></p>

  </ons-page>

</ons-template>

</body>

</html>
```

**javascript**

```
ons.bootstrap();



function MyCtrl($scope,$templateCache) {    

  $scope.pages = [

    {pageId: "Page1", pageTitle: "Page One"},

    {pageId: "Page2", pageTitle: "Page Two"},

    {pageId: "Page3", pageTitle: "Page Three"}

  ];

  $scope.selectPage;



  $scope.loadPage = function(pageId) {

    console.log(pageId);

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.pages.length;i++) {

      if ($scope.pages[i].pageId == pageId) {

        $scope.selectPage = $scope.pages[i];

        break;

      }

    }

    myNavigator.pushPage("templatePage");

  };



  $scope.pageTitle = function () {

    return $scope.selectPage.pageTitle;

  }



  $scope.pageContent = function() {

    return "This is " +  $scope.selectPage.pageTitle;

  }

}
```

See it LIVE here: 'http://codepen.io/vnguyen972/pen/EcIxn'